# Attempt to delete readonly key from a restricted hash, when it is not restricted

Tags: perl, hash

I quite often arrange my subroutine entry like this:

```
sub mySub {
    my ($self, %opts) = @_;
    lock_keys(%opts, qw(count, name));
    ...
    my $name = delete $opts{name};
    $self->SUPER::mySub(%opts);
}
```

to allow calling the sub using named arguments like this:

```
$obj->mySub(count=>1, name=>'foobar');
```

The lock_keys guards against calling the sub with mis-spelled argument names.

The last couple of lines are another common idiom I use, where if I am writing a method that overrides a superclass, I might extract the arguments which are specific to the subclass and then chain a call to the subclass.

This worked fine in perl 5.8, but after upgrading to Centos 6 (which has perl 5.10.1) I started to see seemingly random errors like this:

```
Attempt to delete readonly key 'otherOption' from a restricted hash at xxx.pl line 9.
```

These errors do not happen all the time (even in the same subroutine) but they do seem to relate to the call chain that results in calling the sub which bombs out.

Also note that they do not happen on perl 5.16 ([or at least not on ideone](http://ideone.com/zRCmoJ)).

What is causing these errors in perl 5.10? According to the [manpage for Hash::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Hash/Util.html), `delete()` should still work after lock_keys. It is like the whole hash is getting locked somehow.

Comment: Fixed in 5.14.2, actually.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami; I searched for ages and did not find that. Unfortunately upgrade would not be an easy solution for us though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this even before posting on SO, but the workaround is not great so feel free to chime in with a better one.

This SSCCE exhibits the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Hash::Util qw(lock_keys);

sub doSomething {
        my ($a, $b, %opts) = @_;
        lock_keys(%opts, qw(myOption, otherOption));

        my $x = delete $opts{otherOption};

}

my %h = (
        a=>1,
        b=>2
);

foreach my $k (keys %h) {
        doSomething(1, 2, otherOption=>$k);
}
```

It seems that the problem is related to the values passed in as values to the named argument hash (%opt in my example). If these values are copied from keys of a hash, as in the example above, it marks the values as read-only in such a way that it later prevents deleting keys from the hash.

In fact you can see this using Devel::Peek

```
$ perl -e'
   use Devel::Peek;
   my %x=(a=>1);
   foreach my $x (keys %x) {
      my %y = (x => $x);
      Dump($x);
      Dump(\%y);
   }
'
SV = PV(0x22cfb78) at 0x22d1fd0
  REFCNT = 2
  FLAGS = (POK,FAKE,READONLY,pPOK)
  PV = 0x22f8450 "a"
  CUR = 1
  LEN = 0
SV = RV(0x22eeb30) at 0x22eeb20
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x22f8880
  SV = PVHV(0x22d7fb8) at 0x22f8880
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (PADMY,SHAREKEYS)
    ARRAY = 0x22e99a0  (0:7, 1:1)
    hash quality = 100.0%
    KEYS = 1
    FILL = 1
    MAX = 7
    RITER = -1
    EITER = 0x0
    Elt "x" HASH = 0x9303a5e5
    SV = PV(0x22cfc88) at 0x22d1b98
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (POK,FAKE,READONLY,pPOK)
      PV = 0x22f8450 "a"
      CUR = 1
      LEN = 0
```

Note that the FLAGS for the hash entry are "READONLY" and in fact the variable $x and the value of the corresponding value in %y are actually pointing at the same string (PV = 0x22f8450 in my example above). It seems that Perl 5.10 is trying hard to avoid copying strings, but in doing so has inadvertently locked the whole hash.

The workaround I am using is to force a string copy, like this:

```
foreach my $k (keys %h) {
        my $j = "$k";
        doSomething(1, 2, otherOption=>$j);
}
```

This seems an inefficient way to force a string copy, and in any case is easy to forget, so other answers containing better workarounds are welcome.